# C : use pointer-content as an array parameter

Tags: c, pointers, integer

I want to use two pointers to define my array content. Thats why I have:

```
int *Q1, *Q2;
```

later on (in a function) this shall happen:

```
*Q1 = 11, *Q2 = 2;    
field[*Q1][*Q2]='?';
```

it's important that Q1 and 2 are declared in the function. So they can always be used in main as Q1 and Q2 but can be changed by various functions =/
Can you help me out? At the moment the compiler tells me that the array subscript is not an integer. How do I have to write it down?

Best regards!

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEIGHT 15                       
#define WIDTH 15                        


int field[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

int *Q1, *Q2;


void forest1() {
    int *Q1 = 11, *Q2 = 2; 
    field[2][3]=field[1][11]=field[9][10]=field[5][0]=field[5][14]=field[8][0]=field[8][14]='-';
    field[3][2]=field[2][10]=field[10][9]='(';
    field[3][4]=field[2][12]=field[10][11]=')';
    field[4][3]=field[5][3]=field[3][11]=field[4][11]=field[11][10]=field[12][10]='H';
    field[0][5]=field[0][8]=field[14][5]=field[14][8]='|';
    field[*Q1][*Q2]='?';
}

void printField(){
    int i;
    int i2;
    for (i = 0; i<HEIGHT; i++){ 
        for (i2=0; i2<WIDTH; i2++)
            printf("%3c", field[i][i2]);    
        printf("\n\n");
    }   
}

void initField(){
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i<sizeof(field); i++)       
        field[i%WIDTH][i/WIDTH]=' ';        
}

int main() {
    char direction;
    int h = 7; int w = 7;                   // Starting Point


    initField();
    field[h][w]='o';
    forest1();
    printField();
    printf("Welcome! Move with wasd - have fun testing! \n\n");

int obstacle(char direction) {


    switch(direction) {
        case 'w':   {
            if (field[h-1][w]== '(' || field[h-1][w]== '-' || field[h-1][w]== ')' || field[h-1][w]== 'H' || h-1 < 0)
            return 1;
            else return 0;
            break;
        }
        case 'a':   {
            if (field[h][w-1]== '(' || field[h][w-1]== '-' || field[h][w-1]== ')' || field[h][w-1]== 'H' || w-1 < 0)
            return 1;
            else return 0;
            break;
        }
        case 's':   {
            if (field[h+1][w]== '(' || field[h+1][w]== '-' || field[h+1][w]== ')' || field[h+1][w]== 'H' || h+1 > 14)
            return 1;
            else return 0;
            break;
        }
        case 'd':   {
            if (field[h][w+1]== '(' || field[h][w+1]== '-' || field[h][w+1]== ')' || field[h][w+1]== 'H' || w+1 > 14)
            return 1;
            else return 0;
            break;
        }
        default: return 0; break;
    }

}


void move() {

    while (1) {

        direction = getch();

        if (obstacle(direction)!=1){

                    if (field[*Q1][*Q2]=='o') {
                        /* German content since this will be a german little game. Basically says it's a question block*/
    printf("Hallo! Dies ist ein Infoblock! Er gibt dir wertvolle Informationen.\n");
    system("pause");
}


            if (direction=='w') {
                    field[h][w]=' ';
                    h = h-1;
                    field[h][w]='o';
                }

            if (direction=='a'){
                    field[h][w]=' ';
                    w = w-1;
                    field[h][w]='o';
                }

            if (direction=='s'){
                    field[h][w]=' ';
                    h = h+1;
                    field[h][w]='o';
                }

            if (direction=='d'){
                    field[h][w]=' ';
                    w = w+1;
                    field[h][w]='o';
                }
            system("cls");
            printField();
        }
    }
}



    move(); 

    }
```

The compiler tells me for this exact code: 
"Line 16: [Warning] initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]"
twice, for col 12 and col 22.
When I start the programm It crashes but prints nothing so far

Comment: Show us the actual code that's failing, and the exact error message. Read this first: http://sscce.org/. And C doesn't have array parameters.

Comment: Mhhh, okay. It's meant to be a little game where you move a little avatar ( an 'o') As I want to change the maps I have to change location of question blocks =/ Yet I want movement to stop when the avatar touches a '?'. The code will come separate since the comment has not enough characters

Comment: I'm sure you can reduce that to a much smaller program that still produces the error. And please include the exact error message in the question.

Comment: In the original question, you wrote `field[*Q1][*Q2]='?';`. In the code you just added, you wrote `field[Q1][Q2]='?';`. BTW, in addition to including the error message in the question, you should indicate which line the message refers to. (Don't add line numbering to the entire program, just add a comment saying "This is line so-and-so".)

Comment: This is *rapidly* heading toward an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). The warning(s) are obvious. `int *Q1 = 11;` is converting an `int` value to a pointer-type and the compiler is both right and wise in telling you so. What you're trying to accomplish (not *how* you're trying to accomplish it) remains simultaneously relevant and elusive. Both Q1 and Q2 are automatic to their function decl. If you want they values retained they cannot be so, and must either be passed as parameters or given `static` storage. And your locals hide your globals, in case that wasn't obvious.

Comment: Move the `obstacle` and `move` functions to be before `main()`. Embedding the functions inside `main()` like you have done is terrible style, as well as not being permitted in standard C

Answer (score 3):

you cannot initialize `int *Q1 = 11`.

`int *Q1` is a pointer to an integer variable so it can store only a pointer which points to a variable which can store an integer.

you can initialize/assign `Q1` variable with a pointer only.
`&` is used to get the address of a variable in C.

example:

```
int a = 12;
int *Q1 = &a;
```

Thats why you are getting compiler warning saying  "Line 16: [Warning] initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]"

12 is an integer and you tried to assign it to a pointer to an integer variable and when compiler tried to do implicit type conversion it gave a warning.

```
    if (field[h][w-1]== '(' || field[h][w-1]== '-' || field[h][w-1]== ')' || field[h][w-1]== 'H' || w-1 < 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
    break;
```

This part of the code in your program are called dead code, where the control can never reach, example the `break` statement. try to avoid them.

local variables are local to the function and are not accessible to other function in you program.

Also, you have variables `h, w` which are local to main, but you used all over you program, if you want to use any variable outside of a function,  make them as global variables. if you want them to be modified by calling function then use pass by reference.

Use proper indentation and comments in your code to make them more readable for others and by you also in future.

Comment: Thank you very much ^.^ I'm still learning and I'm sorry for the things that seem obvious ^^'

Comment: No a problem @HannahAround, everybody does mistakes and trick is try not to do it again.